# Copy PDfs Files to shared network and files corrupted

Tags: c#, file, networking, copy

My app Windows forms .NET in Win XP copy files pdfs in shared network folder in a server win 2003.

Admin user in Win2003 detects some corrupt files pdfs, in that shared folder.

HOw can I check if a file is copied right in shared folder ??

the code: I use two ways to copy/move files to shared folder

1. NOte: my app generates PDFs files
2. Write Bytes to disk (the shared folder)

   Public Shared Function GenerarFicheroDeBytes(ByVal datosFichero As Byte(), ByVal rutaFisicaFichero As String) As FileStream

   ```
   If Not Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaFisicaFichero)) Then
       Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaFisicaFichero))
   End If

   Dim fs As New FileStream(rutaFisicaFichero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
   fs.Write(datosFichero, 0, datosFichero.Length)
   fs.Flush()
   fs.Close()
   Return fs
   ```

   End Function

2 Move File to shared network folder

```
Public Function MoverFicheroABuzonParaIndexar(ByVal rutaProcesarFicherosBuzon As String, ByVal nombreFichero As String) As String

Dim nombreFicheroPDF As String = String.Empty
Dim nombreFicheroPDFRenombrado As String = String.Empty
Dim nombreFicheroBuzon As String = String.Empty 

     nombreFicheroPDF = ... Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(...)
     nombreFicheroBuzon = ObtenerRutaFicheroBuzonParaIndexar(...)

      File.Move(nombreFicheroPDF, nombreFicheroBuzon)
Return nombreFicheroBuzon

End Function
```

Comment: How are you copying the files? Care to give us some code examples?

Comment: If your code sample is your actual code, I would advise using the "Using" statement for the file stream to tidy up resources when you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, unless you know the resulting format of the file - the only entity that can tell you if a file is corrupt or not is the application that attempts to use it.  "Corruption" has no context outside of trying to use the file, it's like saying a .doc is corrupt because my CAD application can't read it, only Word can.

Also, File.Copy and File.Move exist as shortcut methods for moving files instead of manually streaming them yourself.

Comment: If is PDF file ??, 2 issues: 1. how detect File Header is correct?. 2. how know if PDF is corrupt ??. thanks

Comment: Not sure, you would need to find out what the correct format is for the PDF file, and any headers, then test the current format against this correct format for validity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, ended up I wasn't waiting long enough for the PDF Printer to finish printing the PDF, and I was only getting the first half or so of the file!  Put a simple loop in my program to fix this:

```
// the file is there, make sure it is not still growing (printing). If it is, wait for it to stop
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(OUTPUTFILEPATH);
long lastLength;
do
{
    lastLength = fi.Length;
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    fi.Refresh();
}
while (fi.Length > lastLength);
```

Comment: I may have a similar issue.  What is the code that is running above this snippet?  How are you generating the file at `OUTPUTFILEPATH`?

Comment: @jayoaK - in our application, AutoCAD was called and passed a script to run, at the end of which it will print the drawing it generates to a PdfCreator printer.  When control comes back to our application, it is basically sitting there waiting to see if the PDF has been generated yet (it knows what path/filename the file will be created at). So the trick was, don't try moving the file until we are sure that not only is it created, but PdfCreator is done writing to the file.